# What are the conditions for the yearling badge?

Tags: support, yearling-badge

Will I get the [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) badge if I:

- am inactive on Stack Overflow
- am less activity
- have not posted anything on SO thus far
- visit the site once in a week
- visit the site once in a month
- visit the site once in a year
- have not visited the site since I created my account?

What are the terms and conditions to get this badge on SO?

Comment: Yes, you'll get it. You have earned the minimum required 200 reputation in the past year, as you can see on [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3160747/starkeen?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terms and condition to get this badge, from the [Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Yearling
>
> - silver; awarded multiple times
> - Have a reputation of at least (number of years as an active user) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)
>
>   - The number of years is not restricted to integers and increases continuously. For example, if at the 2-year mark you don’t have the 400 required reputation, the number of years still continues to increase. So half way through year 3 (i.e., after 2.5 years), you’d need 2.5 × 200 = 500 reputation to qualify for the second yearling badge.
>   - If at any point you qualify for this year‘s badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year whenever the script runs again.
>   - The badge used to require only (years) × 100 reputation; this was [changed after the account association bonus was implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32626)